# Best way to debug knockout data binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Could anyone recommend best ways to debug knockout.js data binding?
Its a bit time consuming to use console.log etc 
What is current best practices in this area?

Thank you,

Pavel

Comment: Use Chrome Knockout Context Debugger tool https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the first comment suggests, the [Chrome Dev Tools KnockoutJS Context Debugger](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fknockoutjs-context-debugg%2Foddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof%3Fhl%3Den&ei=iSwCU7CnII3ykQfX-YHQDQ&usg=AFQjCNEMntah_CIwEBCvgeGrYTwijoJk-Q&sig2=SPpJ8ZFY4akubWRi13oJ-A&bvm=bv.61535280,d.eW0) is extremely useful.

You can also make custom binding handlers that dump out your view model (or parts of it) to JSON. The utility function `ko.toJSON(viewmodel)` can be of use in that regard